# Displaying "loading bar" in Table View Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I've looked around for how to do this, but other than the basics of creating your own table-view cell, I can't figure out how. What I'm trying to do it hard to describe, so I made this image to try and explain:

[image]

So what the program basically does is it plays songs, possible at the same time, after a wait. This entire wait+song is called in my program a cue. Each cue has its own table-view cell, which shows how much of it has played. This is the part I'm struggling with. The best way I can think of to display how much has played is like in the photo, with the blue representing how much of the song has played, the green representing how much of the wait time has played, and the entire thing representing how much of the cue has played. **I can't figure out how to make a table view cell in which I can make an animated bar (b/c the song is playing) with variable amounts of green/blue area. Can anyone help?**

If any of this is unclear or confusing, please comment so I can clarify.

Comment: I guess I don't understand "how much of the wait time has played"

Comment: @AMayes So the total amount of time a Cue takes up is the wait-time + the length of the song. The bar represents how much of the total time has been used and the green/blue show what part of that time is the wait and what part is the music.

Comment: You could try using a custom slider.  They're pretty easy to customize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `backgroundView` property of your cells to a custom subclass of UIView which has a `drawRect` method similar to this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    CGRect blueRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bluePercentage/100.0*rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, blueRect);
    CGRect greenRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.greenPercentage/100.0*rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, greenRect);
}
```

You get the point: fill with white first (default background is black), paint blue bar over it, paint green bar over blue bar. `bluePercentage` and `redPercentage` are properties you'll have to set yourself.

Also, everytime you update the progress, you'll have to call `[cell setNeedsDisplay]` to tell the cell to redraw the progress bar.

Comment: Ok, but what exactly is passed to drawRect? Also, I've looked up the Core Graphics library and I'm a little confused what the CGContext is.

Comment: Also, how do I instantiate the UIView? The init method calls fro a CGRect, so what should I set it to?

Comment: `cell.backgroundView = [[YourCellBackgroundViewClass alloc] init];` seems to be sufficient.

Comment: `drawRect` is a method that is called internally. `rect` is a rectangle with the origin (0, 0) and the same size as the cell. The CGContext tells the system where on the screen this rectangle is. (heavily simplified for you to understand)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This had worked really well and I couldn't find anything else online.